# Google Sheet Apps Script Exceeding maximum time

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, dropdown

I have a dynamic dropdown apps script running on only 1 cell and there are some other formulas running in my sheet. Until 2 days before i could run the script onEdit but i cant seem to do so now.
When checked inside apps script execution page it shows "Exceeded maximum execution time". What can i do to resolve this?

```
var mainWsName = "Print Sheet";
var mainDataName = "Orders";
var FirstLevelColumn = 1;
var SecondLevelColumn = 2;
var ThirdLevelColumn = 3;
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsJO = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainDataName);
var JO = wsJO.getRange(2,1,wsJO.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === mainWsName && c === FirstLevelColumn && r > 1){
     applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r); 
  }else if(wsName === mainWsName && c=== SecondLevelColumn && r > 1){
    applysecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  }
} //end onEdit

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){ 

   if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r,SecondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r,SecondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r,SecondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var filteredJO = JO.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredJO.map(function(o){return o[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,SecondLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
}


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
             
  var rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build();        
  
   cell.setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

Tried executing app script to get dynamic dropdown based on my selection.

Comment: You could just try to convert to Installable because I don't think the 30 second limit applies then.  But it will impact the performance of your spreadsheet and it's certainly not an optimal way of solving the problem.  You should make better use of the event object.

Comment: How do i convert it to an installable? When i checked the 3o second limit is applied when the results are timed out.

Comment: go to the trigger menu or create it programattically

Answer (score 0):

The code you quote is suboptimal, but chances are that the bad performance you mention is caused by the *spreadsheet* rather than the script. To improve spreadsheet performance, see these [optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).

You may also want to take a look at the [dependentDropDownLists_](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160451/269219) script.